# Approximating the standard normal density with the logistic density: How to numerically optimize $\infty$-norm?

Tags: normal-distribution, approximation, numerics, logistic-distribution

Let's say that we want to use the logistic distribution as an approximation to the standard normal density. As the location parameter of the logistic distribution is $0$, the scale parameter $s$ is the only free parameter. We want to choose $s$ in a way so that the **maximum distance between the two density functions is minimized** (i.e. the $\infty$-norm is minimized). How could you do this numerically? What's challenging is that the maximum distance may occur at different $x$ values. You could just supply $x$ values for a range where the maximum is likely to occur, between $-10$ and $10$, say, and choose $s$ so that the maximum distance within this range is minimized. But this seems a bit ad hoc to me.

The question was inspired by [this blog](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2023/11/04/logistic-normal-approximation/) entry by John Cook.

Comment: Approximations based on densities are practically meaningless in statistics, so it would be of some interest to know of a useful application.

Comment: @whuber It's a purely technical question for me: I saw it on the blog post I linked and wondered, how to practically optimize for the $\infty$-norm.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in a principled manner by making use of the following bound on the maximum distance between the tails of the distributions:

$$\max_{x\geq k \geq 0} |f(x)-g(x)| < \max(f(k),g(k))$$

This bound holds because the two distributions are strictly decreasing in the tails and of course, are bounded below by zero. The symmetry of the distributions saves us the effort of worrying about $x \leq k \leq 0$.

With this in hand, your approach can be modified as follows:

1. Choose an initial value for $k$.
2. Solve for the optimal $s$ over $[-k,k]$.  The associated distance we'll denote by $d_s$.
3. If $f(k) \leq d_s$ and $g(k) \leq d_s$, return $s$.  Including the tails won't change the optimal value, which is determined by some $x \in [-k,k]$.
4. Increase $k$, say, $k \leftarrow 2\cdot k$.  Go to 2.

We can solve this numerically with a nested optimization; the inner optimization finds the maximum value of $|f(x;s)-g(x)|$ (where $f$ is the logistic distribution and $g$ is the standard normal distribution) and the outer optimization finds the minimum value of the inner optimization:

$$\min_s \max_x |f(x;s)-g(x)|$$

We implement this in R:

```
inner_maximization <- function(x,s) {
  abs(dlogis(x,0,s) - dnorm(x))
}

outer_minimization <- function(s, k) {
  optimize(inner_maximization, c(0, k), maximum=TRUE, s=s)$objective
}

k <- 5
repeat {
  res <- optimize(outer_minimization, c(0.2, 2.0), k=k)
  if (max(dnorm(k), dlogis(k,0,res$minimum)) < res$objective) break;
  k <- 2*k
}

res
```

which gives us:

```
> res
$minimum
[1] 0.5797709

$objective
[1] 0.005671746
```

Note that we did make an assumption about the range of possible values of $s$, but of course it's easy to check if we are close to a boundary as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm having trouble with step 2 though. How would you solve for the optimal $s$ over $[-k, k]$?

Comment: I'll add that in later today; the short version would be a nested optimization $\min_s \max_x |f(x;s)-g(x)|$, where $f$ is the logistic and $g$ is the standard normal.  That can be done numerically pretty easily.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I believe that the solution is sensitive to $k$ because there can be multiple maxima for the inner maximization. For example: Set $s=0.6237$ and $k=5$. The maximum of $0.01845$ occurs at $x=0.9623$ but the code will output the local maximum of $0.0106$ at $x=2.514$. But even setting the starting value for $k=1.75$, the final result is $s=0.636$. Whereas the optimal $s$ seems to be $0.6237$ with a maximum of $0.01845$. It seems to me that widening the range for $k$ is leading to suboptimal solutions due to local maxima.

Comment: Agreed.  Because this can be a delicate problem, but there are only two variables involved, a grid search can be helpful for assuring the solution is correct.  Bear in mind there is no substitute for graphing the functions involved: that will show how the "outer optimization" concerns a *discontinuous* function (which can cause `optimize` to fail) -- and that's a basic flaw with this approach.

Comment: @whuber - good point.  I'll think about that.